# подключение прокси листа к c#

Tags: c#, proxy

не могу разобраться с задачей  - есть прокси лист , необходимо реализовать метод который бы проверял прокси из этого листа и если подключение прошло удачно возвращал true , если нет возвращал false 
спасибо

Comment: Что не понятно? Как прочесть с листа, или как подключится?

Comment: Вопрос звучит следующим образом: напишите за меня программу, а то я ничего в этом не смыслю. Приведите пример того кода, который вы пытались написать, или всё-же не пытались ?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос поставлен так, что это правильный ответ.

1. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequest.proxy(v=vs.110).aspx
3. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx
4. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx
   5